# Background image positioning, full width, browser height 100%, multiple sections, padding issues

Tags: html, css

Been writing code for the background of a website. The goals are 1) 100% height of the browser window for the first image 2) image stays centered in window and sides are cut off 3) on the home page there is also two additional images that need to have the same effect. Been trying and writing different code chunks and not getting anywhere. I can get one part which just breaks another. Thank you for any assistnaceCurrent code chunk is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Background Image</title>

    <style>

        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        .background { 
            background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="background">
        <img src="images/bg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="background bg2">
        <img src="images/bg2.png">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand what your question is but for your image to get the height of the window you need to

```
.background {
     background-image: url(images/bg.png);
     height: 100vh;
}
```

That way the background image will always use the full height of the viewport. Not sure about the rest of the question tho!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, there are a few things with your code that is wrong. First I will explain a couple of things and then I'll provide the code that I came up with that works when I tested it. Here goes...

First, in your style element, where you have ".background:", you don't need any of the code that you wrote. The stuff that mentions webkit, moz, etc. is really for stuff that may have cross browser compatibility problems. background-size is not one of those things you would have to worry about with that. The only thing I would put in your "background" class is width and height of 100%.

Second, speaking of width and height, I would include and "html" and "body" element and give them both a width and height of 100%.

Third, you are trying to have your images listed in your html, but you are trying to style them as if you are having your css produce them. Notice how in my html I left the "background" divs empty and then included the url of the photos in the css.

In a nutshell, I believe you may be a little confused as to what method should be used and when/where, because you are actually fusing different approaches together. That said, here is the code I wrote...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Background Image</title>
    <style>

        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .background { 
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #bg1 {
            background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #bg2 {
            background: url(images/bg2.pngg) no-repeat center;
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="background" id="bg1">
    </div>
    <div class="background" id="bg2">
    </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a link that may help you too. They have great directions, exercises and tutorials:  [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Hope all of that helps Zack!  :)